# org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/templates/standard.jsp'

Tags: java, spring, apache, jsp, spring-mvc

Hi guys I am getting following exception. Any idea?

**type**

```
Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/templates/standard.jsp'.
```

**description**

The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/templates/standard.jsp'.
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java:58)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    com.amazon.fc.sortation.rebin.web.MetricsFilter.doFilter(MetricsFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

root cause

org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/templates/standard.jsp'.
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:692)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java:58)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    com.amazon.fc.sortation.rebin.web.MetricsFilter.doFilter(MetricsFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

root cause

org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/templates/standard.jsp'.
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:241)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:243)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java:58)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    com.amazon.fc.sortation.rebin.web.MetricsFilter.doFilter(MetricsFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

root cause

java.io.FileNotFoundException: no such file: /tmp/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/views/templates/standard_jsp.class
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil$SDEInstaller.<init>(SmapUtil.java:253)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil$SDEInstaller.install(SmapUtil.java:241)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil.installSmap(SmapUtil.java:165)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler.generateClass(AntCompiler.java:276)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java:58)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    com.amazon.fc.sortation.rebin.web.MetricsFilter.doFilter(MetricsFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Comment: What's your code? What libraries are you using? Have you changed any of the default config settings?

Comment: Yes we are using custom config. Weird thing is in it works in other's machine. It worked on my machine for the first time. After that anytime I run i end up with this exception.
Tiles:
http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd
Apache: 6.039

Comment: Formatted error message. Formatted post to more clarity

Comment: We can't really help you without seeing _your_ code

Comment: @MahmudHoque Have you resolved your error?